# Boostrap dropdown menu is closed on hovering

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown with another dropdown inside it, I added some Jquery code to open/close both dropdowns on hovering.

I hover over the main dropdown `services` and then hover over `service2` which is another dropdown and when I try to go to the element inside it `Service2 sub1`, `Service2 sub2` the dropdown is closed.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Service1</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" class="sub-menu">
                        Service2 <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a></li>
                    <ul>
                    <div id="collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Service2 sub1</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Service2 sub2</a></li>
                    </div>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </li> <!-- .dropdown -->
        </ul> <!-- .navbar-nav -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- .navbar -->
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Stop propagation for the dropdown
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    //On hovering over the main menu 'Services'
    $(".dropdown").hover(
        function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("fast");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        },
        function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    );

    //On hovering over the sub-menu `Services`
    $(".sub-menu").hover(
        function() {
        $('#collapse').removeClass('collapse').addClass('collapse in');
        },
        function() {
        $('#collapse').removeClass('collapse in').addClass('collapse');
        }
    );

});
```

Her is a live fiddle to test https://jsfiddle.net/0ksz9tnL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to point out that your HTML is not valid, you have a `ul` inside a `ul`

look here:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Service1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" class="sub-menu">
        Service2 <b class="caret"></b>
    </a></li>
    <ul>
```

Second, if you then just move the class `sub-menu` from `<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" class="sub-menu">` to it's parent then it works just fine.

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Stop propagation for the dropdown
  $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  //On hovering over the main menu 'Services'
  $(".dropdown").hover(
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("fast");
      $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  );

  //On hovering over the sub-menu `Services`
  $(".sub-menu").hover(
    function() {
      $('#collapse').removeClass('collapse').addClass('collapse in');
    },
    function() {
      $('#collapse').removeClass('collapse in').addClass('collapse');
    }
  );

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Service1</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class="sub-menu">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse">
              Service2 <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul>
              <div id="collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Service2 sub1</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Service2 sub2</a></li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li> <!-- .dropdown -->
    </ul> <!-- .navbar-nav -->
  </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- .navbar -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: So you just moved the `sub-menu` to the parent element?

Comment: @User1804 yer just look at the demo i posted

Comment: Yes I see that, But also you changed the html so that the parent is wrapping more elements and I have no problem with that it just didn't work when I just moved the class

Comment: @User1804 try take a look and make sure your html match the html in the demo i provided, you can see it works there.